# How can I store the values(JTextField & JXDatePicker) into MySQL database?

Tags: java, mysql, swing

Please help me to execute this program:

```
try{
  Connection conn;
    String dbuser = "root";
    String dbpassw = "1209";
    String databasename = "mynewdatabase";
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/" + databasename;
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection (url, dbuser, dbpassw);
    PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("insert into newjframe1 values(?,?)");
    String TicketProjectSOWNo=jTextField1.getText().toString();
    String RELATED_REFERENCES=jTextField2.getText().toString();
    String REPORT_DATE=jXDatePicker3.getDate().toString();
    ResultSet res = ps.executeQuery(); 
    if (res.next()) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Data saved successfully");
    }  
}
catch( Exception e ) {
        System.out.println(e);
}
```

I tried like this but error comes when saving this components in the MySQL database. What is the right coding for this program?

Comment: *"How can i able to store this following swing components(textfield1,textfield2 & jXDatePicker3) into the mysql database?"*  Store the content. I.E.  `String`, `String` and `Date`..

Comment: *"..but error comes.."*  Always copy/paste error and exception output! And change `System.out.println(e);` to `e.printStackTrace();`..

Comment: Short answer is don't, store their values instead

Answer (score 1):

You can edit your code like this

Assuming your table has 3 columns to be inserted

```
 PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("insert into newjframe1 values(?,?,?)");

ps.setString(1,jTextField1.getText().toString());

ps.setString(2,jTextField2.getText().toString());

ps.setString (3,jXDatePicker3.getDate().toString());

int flag = ps.executeUpdate(); 
if (flag!=0) {

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Data saved successfully");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Mistake you have done is not setting the place holder values for the `PreparedStatement`. Set the values into prepared statement using one of the `.setXXX` methods of prepared statement. Then it will save the data to the database.

Title of your question is misleading. You are not saving the swing component to the database. You are only saving the value. Please update the question title.

Comment: Sorry Ravi sir. i dont have enough knowledge to understand this. So please help me better with the coding style

Comment: Read some samples of how to use `PreparedStatement`.

Comment: What is the relationship of that language with this question you posted?

Comment: sorry boss that is my mother tongue. i can explain this program concept correctly. but in english means it is little bit tough to deliver my program concepts

Comment: For being a good developer it is important to be able to communicate effectively in business language like English. First you should learn that properly. Read the answer I have given - it will be clear where the problem is and how to fix it.

Comment: k ji thankyou for helping me. I'll manage how to learn properly and dont worry about that